Any recommendations to enable Firebase Cloud Messaging within MSVS 2022 .NET MAUI app ( C#)? I get path too long errors with plugin.firebase
Windows 11
MSVS 2022
.NET MAUI C# template
When I try to install the plugin.firebase nuget package I get path too long errors
